# How to parse x.509 certificate with WebCrypto?

Tags: javascript, x509, deno, webcrypto

The following certificate (it's publicly available, don't worry about it) was generated by Microsoft in order to validate the authenticity of JWT generated tokens

`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`

I'd like to know how it would be possible to import it as a key with WebCrypto (not interested in other libraries ATM), so far I've had no luck

The attempted code has been

```js
// Extracted from WebCrypto examples
function stringToArrayBuffer(string) {
  const buf = new ArrayBuffer(string.length);
  const bufView = new Uint8Array(buf);
  for (let i = 0, strLen = string.length; i < strLen; i++) {
    bufView[i] = string.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return buf;
}

const key = await crypto.subtle.importKey(
  "spki",
  stringToArrayBuffer(atob(the_certificate_without_headers)),
  {
    name: "RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5",
    hash: "SHA-256",
  },
  true,
  ["verify"],
);
```

The above fails with `DOMException: unexpected ASN.1 DER tag: expected OBJECT IDENTIFIER, got CONTEXT-SPECIFIC [0] (constructed) at DER byte 8`

Comment: I do not work with that library, but none of the code looks correct. Do not remove the header or trailer on PEM certificates. You mentioned examples, provide a link to them. PEM public keys are base64 encoded. That means your string to arraybuffer code is wrong. You are declaring the format "spki" which means you probably want to do: `var subjectPublicKeyInfo = forge.pki.publicKeyToAsn1(publicKey);  var der = forge.asn1.toDer(subjectPublicKeyInfo).getBytes();` to convert the PEM to DER and then `crypto.subtle.importKey('spki', str2ab(der), ...`

Comment: @JohnHanley The examples I cited are the following https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/importKey#subjectpublickeyinfo_import

I'm not interested in using any third party libraries

Comment: Your code is trying to import an X.509 certificate but is written to import a public key. Extract the public key from the certificate first. Since you are not interested in third-party libraries, you must write that code yourself.